# Example of weakly separated function

Tags: analysis, functions

A function $f:X \rightarrow Z$, where $X$ is a topological space and $Z$ is a metric space, is called *weakly separated* if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a neighbourhood assignment $(V_x)_{x \in X}$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))\leq \epsilon$ whenever $(x,y) \in V_y \times V_x$.

The definition is extracted from the paper 'the point of continuity property neighbourhood assignments and filter convergences' by Ahmed Bouziad.

I am having difficulty to understand the definition.

Suppose $X=Z=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x$. Then my difficulty is I don't know how to find $(V_x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$. Can anyone enlighten me?

EDIT(1): a neighbourhood assignment means that each $V_x$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$.

EDIT (2): May I know what is the intuition behind the definition?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you can let $V_x$ be the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$, ie the open interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$.  Then, if $(x,y) \in V_y \times V_x$, you have $x\in V_y$ and $y\in V_x$ both implying that $|x-y| < \epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: but according to the definition, $V_x$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X=\mathbb{R}$. Can we let $V_x$ as what you mention in your answer? In the example, I let $V_x$ to be an open interval containing $x$.

Comment: I have edited my answer to write out the neighborhood as an explicit interval.

Comment: how do you draw $(x,y) \in V_y \times V_x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$? For example, $(1,2) \in V_2 \times V_1$